# How to output a PS object as a custom formatted string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an object with a set of properties (depth: 1). How to output the object as a string in a format like this:

`{property1_name:property1_value} {property2_name:property2_value} {property3_name...`

(the above is a single line, but property values can of course have newlines/carriage returns etc)

Let's assume I do not know the property names, they can change.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll actually depend on what object you're looking through. I tested this out on a csv, and it works decently, although you may want to do some minor formatting for a different type of object.

```
$csv |
    Get-Member |
    Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"} |
    Select-Object -Property Name | 
    ForEach-Object {
        "{" + $_.Name + " : " + $csv.($_.Name) + "}"
    }
```

For example, depending on what you see when you do `$csv | Get-Member`, you may want to change `NoteProperty` to `Property` or something else. This should probably work though.

Note that you also have to change the name of the variable (currently `$csv`) in two places.

Comment: Can I also just comment on how meta powershell is. I love how you can do $csv.$_ to retrieve a property by the property's name through a variable so casually.

Comment: If you replace `-Property Name` with `-ExpandProperty Name`, you can use `$_` instead of `$_.Name` in the `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: @MaximeFranchot I've got a simple "flat" object mostly with string properties. Using your code example and changing NoteProperty to Property I'm able to get property names but not values. I obviously changed $csv to the right variable name.

Comment: @gms0ulman thank you, I will try that, perhaps it will fix the issue where I can see property names but not property values. Does it mean the code should become `"{" + $_ + " : " + $csv.($_) + "}"` ?

Comment: @Alex By if you can get the property, then once pipelined you should be able to use `$_` as the reference to the property. Try without `.Name` first, then try with if the previous didn't work. I played around until everything worked, for example, by commenting out the last pipeline until the output of the previous looked exactly how I wanted.